# Where to define error messages

Tags: c#, static

I'm making my first "real" C# program and I'm thinking about where I should define error messages? Should I do something like this:

```
static class Error
{
    public static string Example { get { return "Example Error"; } }
}
```

I could also use values here instead of properties but that would still mean I can't do something like this:

```
public static string FailedToParse(string filepath, string exmessage)
{
    return ("Failed to parse " + filepath + ".\n" + exmessage);
}
```

So, is that a good idea? Should I make a new class and write a method for each error? How do you guys implement this and why?

I already read

1. [In C#, what's the best way to store a group of constants that my program uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724025/in-c-whats-the-best-way-to-store-a-group-of-constants-that-my-program-uses)
2. [The right way to use Globals Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094708/the-right-way-to-use-globals-constants)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something everything should figure out by themselves.

One like to display nice messages to users another just throw those default generated ones.

Personally I like to have codes for errors.

Something like this:

I create a static class called ExceptionFactory and just pass the code to the method called RaiseException.

```
public static class ExceptionRegions
{
  public static int Internet = 0xA;
  public static int FileSystem = 0xB;
}

public class InternetConnectionException : Exception
{
  public InternetConnectionException () : base("No internet connection available") { }
}

public class FileSystemAccessException : Exception
{
  public FileSystemAccessException () : base("Access to specified path caused an error") { }
}

public static class ExceptionFactory
{
  public static void RaiseException(int code)
  {
    switch(code)
    {
      case ExceptionRegions.Internet : throw new InternetConnectionException();
      ...
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Btw, this is a well known pattern called Factory Pattern. :)

Why I like this, because it allows me to set regions in my application.
Usually an application has many interfaces such as file system, or web services, or database and all I need to do is create a code for each area and the factory will throw a nice message to user without exposing to the user name of database and number of code line or whatever the default generated error message looks alike.